# Why would picture become purple when it's times 255?

Tags: python, image, matplotlib, normalization

First I scale a RGB image to [0,1], then it is ok showed in matplotlib.

Then I recover it (by times 255), and show it, but it became purple, as shown in the pictures I paste below.

What is the reason? How to solve it? What is the correct way to rescale a image to [0,255]?

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.image as mpimg

dog = mpimg.imread('1.jpg')
dog = dog / 255
plt.subplot(121)
plt.imshow(dog) #Normal and ok here
plt.title(('/255'))

dog = dog*255
plt.subplot(122)
plt.imshow(dog) # Purple image, not ok
plt.title('*255')

plt.savefig('out.jpg')
plt.show()
```

[image: sample images]

=============================a line here==========================

Suggested by @BruceWayne, I try to *-255 instead of *255, and it works.

But what is the reason? Why would a picture with values in [-255, 0] showed normal, and one with [0,255] go different way?

Comment: Looks like the negative of the original.

Comment: What does `*-255` do?

Comment: @ BruceWayne  amazing! It works by *-255!  But I think *255 the reversed prosedure of /255,  not *-255. It doesn't make sense for me. Why it works？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When I tried your program, I got a warning saying "Clipping input data to the valid range for imshow with RGB data ([0..1] for float or [0..255] for integers)."

When you first load the image, it is made up from integers in the 0..255 range, which imshow displays normally. When you divide this by 255, it turns into floats in the [0..1] range which, again, imshow displays normally.

Then you multiply by 255, turning it into floats in the [0..255] range, and this imshow does not know what to do with!

I tried changing it back into integers using

```
import numpy as np
dog = (dog * 255).astype(np.uint8)
```

(there's probably some better way of doing that) and then it displays normally again.

Comment: Thx bro, the key point is that I have forgot that the values  if a image range from 0 to 255 should be intergers.

Answer (score 0):

In here `dog = mpimg.imread('1.jpg')` you assign `dog` to image data which is color value for each pixel [reference](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.1/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.imread.html), then you multiply each pixel by 255 and result assigned to resulting image's each pixel values. That's why it's having that color.(Negative image)

Comment: Thx bro.But I am still confused. The original values of this image is from 0 to 255, then I divide it by 255 (scale it and get new_image with values from 0 to 1). I think get the new_image times 255 then I can get the exactly same original image. What is the promblem of my ideal?